Inductive Limit Topology Density of $C_c(G) \diamond C_c(G)$ in $C_c(G \times G)$
While reading an excerpt about function algebras and the inductive limit topology, I came across a remark stating the following:

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and define $C_c(G) \diamond C_c(G) := \text{span}(f \in C_c(G \times G)  |  f(s,t) = h(s)g(s^{-1}t),  h,g \in C_c(G) )$.  Then this collection is inductive limit topology dense in $C_c(G \times G)$.

It's clear to me that $C_c(G) \odot C_c(G) = \text{span}(f \in C_c(G \times G) | f(s,t)=h(s)g(t), h,g \in C_c(G))$ is inductive limit topology dense in this collection (namely by the norm density of this collection in $C_0(G) \otimes C_0(G)$ and thus in $C_c(G \times G)$), but the left translation part is throwing me off.  I was attempting to use a partition of unity argument to solve this, but I kept getting a single term off in the end, by a margin of a point landing in a shift of a neighborhood and not the neighborhood I need.
Any help would be appreciated in helping me solve this, thanks!

The map $\Phi: C_c(G \times G) \to C_c(G \times G)$ defined by,
$$\Phi(f)(s, t) = f(s, s^{-1}t)$$
is clearly continuous and it has a continuous inverse,
$$\Phi^{-1}(f)(s, t) = f(s, st)$$
Thus, $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism. It is not hard to see that $\Phi(C_c(G) \odot C_c(G)) = C_c(G) \diamond C_c(G)$. Thus, as $C_c(G) \odot C_c(G)$ is dense, so is $C_c(G) \diamond C_c(G)$.
